# How can I disable Google Apps Email catch-all email routing?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

[Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962) gives instructions for configuring catch-all email addresses, and differentiates between how it works for "free" Google Apps and "other editions" (paid) Google Apps.

We have a grandfathered-free Google Apps setup, and I configured catch-all email long ago. Now I want to disable it, but it seems the option has been removed.

According to this page, [email routing is no longer available](https://support.google.com/a/answer/77182) in the "free" version of Google Apps. I've wandered-through the Google Admin Console and I can't seem to find a way to modify this configuration.

Am I stuck with this setting until we upgrade to paid-Google Apps?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a looooong time, but I just stumbled across the setting for the catch-all email address.

If you manage to get yourself to the `Apps > G Suite > Settings for Gmail > Advanced settings` page, it's listed at the bottom.

Changing the setting from *Forward the email to...* to *Discard the email* changes the behavior of incoming messages to bounce instead of being delivered to the (previous) catch-all email address.

I find the term "discard" to be misleading, because the message is not discarded -- it's bounced, which means something else entirely.